# iptables should block ssh, but port is still open

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I am trying to get the port knocking service working on my raspberry pi. I have edited my iptables rules to block incoming traffic, but I can still ssh into the pi from my macbook. I should NOT be able to do this, if I'm understanding the iptables rules correctly.

My pi actually did block ssh momentarily when I tested my iptables configuration. But after I installed knockd and started the service, I can ssh without issue again.... even though that is the opposite of what should happen.

from my pi:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination




nano /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May  4 23:53:23 2016
*filter
:INPUT DROP [469:58510]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1788:276430]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  4 23:53:23 2016
```

From my macbook, after I closed the session so it wouldn't hit the `ESTABLISHED` rule

```
ssh user@pi.local
user@pi.local's password:
# enter password and it logs me in
```

EDIT

Actually, none of my iptables rules are being respected. I've blocked literally everything and still get the prompt to log in to ssh; I even get the bullcrap apache index page from the server when I go to that IP in the browser.

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

About to kick a baby...

Comment: add the rule from the input chain to the forward chain, and set forward to drop.  The traffic maybe going through the forward chain.

Comment: @cybernard I've updated `FORWARD` to `DROP` and the problem persists. I also have `pam` setup in my ssh config if that matters...

Comment: did you also add :-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: @cybernard No I didn't, but I can work on iptables accepting traffic after I get it to successfully block traffic.

Comment: try **-A INPUT -j DROP** to see if the policy setting is working. As the last rule.

Comment: @cybernard Please see my edit.

Comment: @cybernard Adding that last rule did block me from accessing apache, but still get the prompt in my terminal to log in.

Comment: did you upgrade your software at all?  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
My pi2 has iptables 1.6.0 and you have 1.4.21 according to your save file.
iptables --version

Comment: @cybernard I've done `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade iptables` and I still get version 1.4.21

Comment: if you stop the knockd service and have the iptables -A INPUT -j DROP  rules does that cut off your ssh access?

Comment: @cybernard It does not.

Comment: iptables -L    Does that show 1. accept related,established 2.  INPUT -j DROP

Comment: @cybernard Yes it does. It's exactly like the first iptables -L in my post, but with the new line `DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere` and the default is still DROP

Comment: **iptables -L -v -t nat**  then **iptables -L -v -t raw**  rules in this area are not normally shown.